# Can anyone identify this tiny 2.4/5.8GHz antenna connector?

Tags: rf, connector, antenna, identification

I'm looking to add a pigtail and larger antenna to small wireless video receiver. It came with a removable antenna with a connector I don't recognize. Sorry for the blurry pictures. If they're not helpful I can try again. It's a push on, and the center of it has the white plastic bit I've seen on RP-TNC connectors. The numbers on the tape in the images are centimeters.

[image: Tiny Antenna front]
[image: Tiny Antenna side]

Comment: [This may be useful](https://www.google.co.nz/search?tbm=isch&oq=&gs_l=&q=5.8%20ghz%20connector#q=5.8+ghz+antenna+connector+rf&tbm=isch) or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite hard to tell but here is some hints on possibilities:

- MMCX connector: used for wifi antenna in notebooks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMCX_connector
- U.FL connector: also used for wifi antenna in notebooks, but more recent
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL
- MC-Card connector ( http://www.deltarf.com/pdf/DeltaMCcard.pdf )

The connector you have seems to be to long for the small U.FL, also the U.FL central pin seems to big to fit your connector.

I'll said that's a MMCX connector but not sure at 100%.

Comment: Dimensions seem to match with MMCX. For example on the photo the part of the connector which extrudes from the insulator is about 4 mm long. [This](http://www.rfcoaxconnectors.com/image/img-tech-interface-MCX.jpg) image under F shows the length of 4 mm to 4.12 mm. The diameter seems to be close as well. Also it's waaaay too large to be U.FL connector. They're just a few mm thick long.

Comment: I haven't had time to go buy an mmcx pigtail, but I agree that looking at various images online, this seems to be right. I'll mark this as the correct answer for now.